# Jquery Living Elements

Tags: jquery, effect

Does anybody know how to deal with the effect at http://2crossmedia.com/liv-multicolor/
If you click into the text field, its surrounded by a color-changing line.
The code says it's jquery. But how :) ?

A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty cool. It uses 3 images:

- http://2crossmedia.com/liv-multicolor/images/input-mask.png
- http://2crossmedia.com/liv-multicolor/images/gradient.png
- http://2crossmedia.com/liv-multicolor/images/input-bg.png

The mask is a semi-transparent png with transparent parts where the gradient comes through. So they just fade in the gradient behind the mask. Then they just pan it using a timeout. Something like:

```
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="gradient"></div>
<div id="front"></div>
```

`#gradient` starts out with `opacity = 0`. Then you do something like: `$("#gradient").fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source of the scripts using firebug, you can see that they are animating the background image.  The image is mulicolor, and wider than the display.  They are changing the position of the image to give it the illusion that it is fading colors.
Here's the [image](http://2crossmedia.com/liv-multicolor/images/gradient.png) they are using.